# Is there a way to get Chrome Canary to auto-update?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to get Google Chrome Canary to auto-update to the latest build / version? So that I really can have and test in the bleeding-edge of the web.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.omgchrome.com/5-reasons-to-use-google-chrome-canary/, it does, and daily at that.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably not auto updating because of your OS settings, the "Google Update Service" will have to be running in the background. If your using windows then you can go to msconfig.exe -> services(tab) and just check the checkbox for "Google Update Service (gupdate)" and "Google Update Service (gupdatem)" and click Apply.